What is the C# array type `System.Int32[*]`?
I'm translating some code from another language that uses 1-based arrays, and I thought it might be useful to use custom bounds. I know that C# allows for specification of lower bounds in multidimensional arrays via this overload of Array.CreateInstance:
var foo = (int[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), [10, 10], [1, 1]);
Console.WriteLine(foo[10, 10]); // Works!

However, I can only get this to work for multidimensional arrays. This doesn't fail when I create the array, but I don't know how to use it.
var foo = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), [10], [1]);
Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType()); // Prints "System.Int32[*]"

What is this type? Can I use it? Casting to an int[] fails. I know it's easy enough to create a wrapper class with a custom indexer. This is more out of curiosity.

@BhavaneshN Thanks! I searched forever but could not find that.
